# gSoap unfriedly error during creation of .h from .wsdl

Tags: c++, c, soap, gsoap

I am trying to produce .h file from .wsdl using gsoap:

```
wsdl2h.exe -v -s -c++11 -o a.h a.wsdl
```

With `a.wsdl` it is working like a charm, but with `b.wsdl` I am getting the unfriendly error:

```
SOAP 1.1 fault SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"End of file or no input: message transfer interrupted"
Detail: [no detail]
```

Any idea how to find out a rootcause of this? I suppose it is something with .wsdl or .xsd file, but how to identify it? Both .wsdl files are not created by me, but on first sight they look fine. When I imported problematic b.wsdl into SOAPUI i was able to send request / receive response.

I also tried this web:

https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/

But unsuccesfully, it is showing me error also on a.wsdl which works fine with gSoap.

Comment: It is not clear when you get this error, when you run wsdl2h or when you run a client developed from b.wsdl?

Comment: @Dr.AlexRE I am getting this error when I run wsdl2h, it means I am even not able to develop a client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some whitespace which was preventing wsdl2h in parsing the wsdl / xsd file.